# Sphinx Wordforms Unexplained Behavior

Tags: sphinx

I added the following to our Sphinx Wordforms list and rebuilt the index:

```
emery paper > glasspaper
emerypaper > glasspaper
sand paper > glasspaper
sandpaper > glasspaper
```

All our product descriptions in the index read as "glasspaper" so you would think this was correct.

However, while I can successfully search for "emery paper" and "sand paper", if I search for "emerypaper" or "sandpaper" I get no results.

Does anyone have an explanation for this? Is a dictionary somehow intervening because these compound words don't exist?

Comment: In sphinx there is no such dictionary, but is it possible there in an intermediate system doing something to the query?  What does SHOW META, show for these queries?

Comment: Thanks for responding Barry. I'm not sure what SHOW META for a query means, did you mean to dump the result set from the query?  I would have to do this for a query that returns results, otherwise the result would "presumably" be empty.

Comment: Ah, SHOW META is from sphinx QL, shows the breakdown of how the query was tokenized, it can give clues on if words transformed. http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-show-meta

Comment: If using API, try a `print_r($res['words'])` to get similar thing (assuming $res is the return from RunQuery)

Comment: I did a "SHOW META" query immediately after the search query and then did print_r on the result, but all I get is "mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 2 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 6 [type] => 0 ) " which is not exactly what I was expecting, according to the Sphinx documentation (thanks for the link).

Comment: You appear to be just trying to dump the result object, can't do that. Need to loop though and fetch the rows http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-row-examples